# ML.NET IDataView back to csv

Tags: c#, csv, machine-learning, ml.net

Assume I have this sample data:

**Sample.csv:**

```
Dog,25
Cat,23
Cat,20
Dog,0
```

And I want to load it to the `IDataView`, the transform it to be ready for ML (without strings and so), then save it again as `.csv`, say to analyze it with another tool or languages.

```cs
// Load data:
var sampleCsv = Path.Combine("Data", "Sample.csv");
var columns = new[]
{
    new TextLoader.Column("type", DataKind.String, 0),
    new TextLoader.Column("age", DataKind.Int16, 1),
};
var mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);
var dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile(sampleCsv, columns,',');

// Transform
var pipeline =
    mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("type",
        // This outputKind will add just one column, while others will add some:
        outputKind: OneHotEncodingEstimator.OutputKind.Key);
var transformedDataView = pipeline.Fit(dataView).Transform(dataView);
//  transformedDataView:
//  Dog,1,25
//  Cat,2,23
//  Cat,2,20
//  Dog,1,0
```

How to get the two numbers columns and write them to the `.csv` file?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes. Moving to `pandas` package in `Python` :-(

Comment: No answer, but could you share how you got "Dog" and "Cat" as results in your transformedDataView ? I am currently hanging on a similar problem, where i can not get the actual labels out of the transformed dataview

Comment: You can check [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/3829). Maybe C# is not good for dynamic types

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `class` for your output data:

```cs
class TempOutput
{
    // Note that the types should be the same from the DataView
    public UInt32 type { get; set; }
    public Int16 age { get; set; }
}
```

Then use [`CreateEnumerable<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.dataoperationscatalog.createenumerable) to read all rows from the `DataView` and print them to `.csv. file:

```cs
File.WriteAllLines(sampleCsv + ".output",
    mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<TempOutput>(transformedDataView, false)
    .Select(t => string.Join(',', t.type, t.age)));
```

Comment: I am not satisfied with this answer. Cross-linking to [Github Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/3829).

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code in my own project to create a .csv file. Hope this helps.

```
var predictions = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<SpikePrediction>(transformedData, reuseRowObject: false);

SavePredictions(predictions.ToArray());

private void SavePredictions(SpikePrediction[] predictions) {
if (dict.Count() != predictions.Count()) {
    Console.WriteLine("> Cannot save predictions because it does not correspond with the dataset length");
    return;
}
List<string> predictionsCol = _dataCol.ToList();
predictionsCol.Add("Label");

var fullResultFilePath = Path.Combine(_dataPath, FileHandeling.resultFolder, $"{_modelName}.csv");
using (var stream = File.CreateText(fullResultFilePath)) {
    stream.WriteLine(string.Join(",", predictionsCol));
    for (int i = 0; i < predictions.Count(); i++) {
        var label = predictions[i];
        stream.WriteLine(string.Join(",", new string[] { dict[i].Item1.Split("T")[0].Substring(1), dict[i].Item2, label.Prediction[0].ToString() }));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Mind showing the example of SpikePrediction? How do you make a class with Vector types?